# Deleting entry in database using context.remove(class) win universal app c#

Tags: entity-framework, win-universal-app

I tried deleting an entry from database using a sql type of command using `from` and `where` and it worked after executing `db.SaveChanges()`. I have seen other examples using a newly created `Person np = new Person() { Name: "sample"};` and passing it as a parameter to `db.Remove(np)` but I am catching this error

```
error Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0
row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.
```

here's the working code

```
Person mm = (from pp in db.People where pp.Name == "sample" select pp)
              .FirstOrDefault();
db.People.Remove(mm);
```

however this doesn't

```
var m = new Person() { Name = "sample" };
db.Remove(m);
```

Can someone enlighten me pls? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to remove a record without giving an Id. You can't remove a record when it doesn't have an Id.

The first case works because you select the Person from the database. So the Person object contains *(or should contain)* an Id.

The second piece of code just creates a new Person without inserting it in the DB.

```
    var id = (from pp in db.People where pp.Name == "sample" select pp).FirstOrDefault().Id; //Get id from person with name "sample"
    var m = new Person() {Id = id};
    db.People.Remove(m);
```

Comment: Well of course the Id should exist in your database

Comment: Updated to use your name == "sample". It gets the Id from the person with name sample and then deletes it from the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [`DbContext.Remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext#Methods_) method to delete an entry, you should be able to set ID to the Person.

If we get the ID and set it to the `Person` and call the `DbContext.Remove`, it will throw the `System.InvalidOperationException`:

> 'The instance of entity type 'Person' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked. 
>   When adding new entities, for most key types a unique temporary key value will be created if no key is set (i.e. if the key property is assigned the default value for its type). 
>   If you are explicitly setting key values for new entities, ensure they do not collide with existing entities or temporary values generated for other new entities. 
>   When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached to the context.'

If the current `DbContext` is released, and we can create new `DbContext` that we use the `DbContext.Remove` method. If you know the ID of the Person, you can use the `DbContext.Remove` method. If not, it is not recommend.

The following code works:

```
int myId;
using (var db = new BloggingContext())
{
    var id = (from pp in db.People where pp.Name == "sample" select pp).FirstOrDefault().PersonId;
    myId = id;
}       
using (var db = new BloggingContext())
{
    var person = new Person() { PersonId = myId};
    db.Remove(person);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```